# Installing taps using gem

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

I am building a facebook app using heroku. I used:

```
gem install taps
```

It gave error:

```
extconf.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError) from extconf.rb:36
```

I googled it and found the stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror) 
I then used:

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev build-essential
```

then I again tried:

```
gem install taps
```

It gave error:

```
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing
```

I installed sqlite3 using sudo apt-get install sqlite3 but when I tried again
(`gem install taps`) it still gives the error:

```
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the dev package for sqlite3:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```