# ruby - json cannot succeed with install bundle

Tags: ruby, json, installation, bundle

I an trying to install redmine but get an issue when I do bundle install

An error occured while installing json (1.7.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Have very little ruby experience so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without further information, it's going to be hard to help you. What about the full error message from `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` ?

Comment: /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from extconf.rb:1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter this kind of error `extconf.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- [something] (LoadError)`, it means that a package on your system is missing.

On Ubuntu for instance, you can install `mkmf` which is part of `ruby18-dev` like this :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby18-dev
```

Comment: was close enough - this worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror