# bson_ext fails on ubuntu

Tags: bson

I have installed all the dependencies for pophealth:

"https://github.com/pophealth/popHealth/wiki/Installation"

but when I run `Bundle Install` I receive the following error:

```
Gem:Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
from extconf.rb:1



Gem Files will remain installed in /home/pophealth/.bundler/tmp/3335/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1 for inspection
results logged to /home/pophealth/.bundler/tmp/3335/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1/ext/cbson/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bson_ext (1.5.1), and bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that 'gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1'' succeeds before bundling.
```

when I run `gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1'` i receive the following error

[image]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror): `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev`

Comment: I'm sure you notice the file permission error. I am looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: you could do a `chmod 777 -R /usr/lib/rub/gems` to fix the file permission issue.