# Rails installation failed on Ubuntu with "cannot load such file -- mkmf"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this problem while installing Rails on Ubuntu 11:

```
root@salah:/home/salah/rubygems-1.8.15# sudo gem install mysql

Fetching: mysql-2.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You have a problem to install the mysql gem, not Rails right? Anyway, I'm not sure the mysql gem is still maintained ... the `mysql2` gem is now the standard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 75):

mkmf is part of the ruby-dev package if I'm not mistaken. Try:

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Of course you may be better off installing ruby through RVM :)

Answer (score 66):

For ubuntu 13.04, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: "sudo apt-get install ruby-dev" will not work if you had ubuntu 12.04 with ruby 1.9.1 and then upgraded to 14.04. First of all you need to delete ruby as "sudo apt-get remove ruby", then install as "sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3", and only after that you can install ruby-dev, otherwise you will have dependency issue.

Answer (score -1):

try 
    `rvm all do gem install nokogiri`