# Error during rails install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion

```
Saads-Mac-Pro:~ SMD$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0- p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:54: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
--with-atomic_reference-dir
--without-atomic_reference-dir
--with-atomic_reference-include
--without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
--with-atomic_reference-lib
--without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The  compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
from /Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.13/ext/gem_make.out
```

This is the output when i run this command `gem install rails`. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:**

Output of `gem env`:

```
Saads-Mac-Pro:~ SMD$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: hope you need to install `dev kit`..Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific? i have installed the xcode command line tools! what else do i need?

Comment: @RajarshiDas help please.

Comment: Which OS you are using? Have you installed Ruby?If yes Version?

Comment: mac os x 10.8.2. ruby version ==> ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0] @ѕтƒ

Comment: @SaadMasood please post `gem -v` and `gem env`

Comment: `Saads-Mac-Pro:~ SMD$ gem -v
2.0.7`

Comment: @RajarshiDas i have updated the question with your required info

Comment: @SaadMasood got it `Gem files will remain installed in /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.` so it is for `gem` name as `atomic` and you required `java jdk 8`  https://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic last line `As of 1.1.0, JDK8 is required to build the atomic gem, since it attempts to use the new atomic `

Comment: 100% sure you do not have JDK 8

Comment: installing JDK8. will get back to you as soon as its done

Comment: ok.....reply me..it will definitely worked but I have one question why rails required atomic rails should not require run time dependency for atomic

Comment: should i install jdk7 or 8?

Comment: i dont have any clue. i just wanted to get started with rails. Tried setting up the environmnt but ran into this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i figured it out after following various articles.

Follow are the Steps.

`$rvm get head`

`$rvm --force 2.0.0`

`$gem update`

`$gem install rails`

went through smoothly.

Following is the output:

```
Saads-Mac-Pro:~ SMD$ gem install rails

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:54: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
Successfully installed atomic-1.1.13
Fetching: thread_safe-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.1.2
Fetching: activesupport-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.0.0
Fetching: builder-3.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.1.4
Fetching: rack-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.5.2
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.2
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: actionpack-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.0.0
Fetching: activemodel-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-4.0.0
Fetching: arel-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-4.0.0
Fetching: activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Fetching: activerecord-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-4.0.0
Fetching: mime-types-1.24.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-1.24
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.3
Fetching: treetop-1.4.15.gem (100%)
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.15
Fetching: mail-2.5.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mail-2.5.4
Fetching: actionmailer-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionmailer-4.0.0
Fetching: thor-0.18.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.18.1
Fetching: railties-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-4.0.0
Fetching: hike-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed hike-1.2.3
Fetching: tilt-1.4.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tilt-1.4.1
Fetching: sprockets-2.10.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-2.10.0
Fetching: sprockets-rails-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-2.0.0
Fetching: rails-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for atomic-1.1.13
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/atomic_reference.bundle, skipping
Installing ri documentation for atomic-1.1.13
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.1.2
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.1.2
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for builder-3.1.4
/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding : ignored
/Users/SMD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding  ignored
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.1.4
Parsing documentation for rack-1.5.2
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.5.2
Parsing documentation for rack-test-0.6.2
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.6.2
Parsing documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Parsing documentation for actionpack-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for activemodel-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for arel-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for arel-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for activerecord-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for mime-types-1.24
Installing ri documentation for mime-types-1.24
Parsing documentation for polyglot-0.3.3
Installing ri documentation for polyglot-0.3.3
Parsing documentation for treetop-1.4.15
Installing ri documentation for treetop-1.4.15
Parsing documentation for mail-2.5.4
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/mail/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for mail-2.5.4
Parsing documentation for actionmailer-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for actionmailer-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for thor-0.18.1
Installing ri documentation for thor-0.18.1
Parsing documentation for railties-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for railties-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for hike-1.2.3
Installing ri documentation for hike-1.2.3
Parsing documentation for tilt-1.4.1
Installing ri documentation for tilt-1.4.1
Parsing documentation for sprockets-2.10.0
Installing ri documentation for sprockets-2.10.0
Parsing documentation for sprockets-rails-2.0.0
Installing ri documentation for sprockets-rails-2.0.0
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/book_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x91" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/chapters_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/check_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/credits_pic_blank.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/csrf.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/edge_badge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x9E" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/favicon.ico, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/feature_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/footer_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/fxn.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/challenge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/confirm_dialog.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/forbidden_attributes_for_new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/form_with_errors.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/index_action_with_edit_link.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/post_with_comments.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/rails_welcome.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_controller.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_route_matches.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/show_action_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/template_is_missing_posts_new.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/undefined_method_post_path.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_create_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_new_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/grey_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/habtm.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_backdrop.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_html_safe.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_localized_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_en.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translation_missing.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_untranslated.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/1.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/10.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/11.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/12.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/13.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/14.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/15.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/2.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/3.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/4.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/5.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/6.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/7.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/8.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/9.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/caution.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/example.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/home.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/important.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/next.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/note.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/prev.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/tip.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/up.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/warning.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/jaimeiniesta.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/nav_arrow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/oscardelben.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/polymorphic.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/radar.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails4_features.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_kindle_cover.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xEC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_logo.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_logo_remix.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/session_fixation.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_grey.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_info.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_note.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_red.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/vijaydev.jpg, skipping
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.0
24 gems installed
```

> Sorry couldn't edit the terminal output. Too many lines!

Answer (score 2):

Installed convmv 1.12-2 ( Ubuntu 12.04.3 ), to solve

- unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping

Comment: Is that a gem to install or an apt-get command?  What commands did you use?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that helped me: [Ruby on Rails - unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for xxx/xxxx/xxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235293/ruby-on-rails-unable-to-convert-x89-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-for-xxx-xxxx-x)

You need to update / install a version of the rdoc gem that supports the conversion. Then these errors won't appear during generation of the documentation when you install rails or when you regenerate the documentation.

```
gem install rdoc
```

Then to regenerate the documentation

```
gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

then do `gem update` and `gem install rails`

Also, make sure that rvm is a function `type rvm | head -1`

Answer (score 1):

got it Look into your error:--

`Gem files will remain installed in /Users/SMD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.13

for inspection`. so it is for gem name as`atomic`and you required`java jdk 8github.com/headius/ruby-atomic
 `last line  stated as of`1.1.0`,`JDK8
 is required to build the atomic gem, since it attempts to use the new atomic`

Please install JDK 8

Comment: just forced rvm to install 2.0.0 version

Comment: @SaadMassod without JDK can you able to install `atomic` ? and your previous error is showing that `atomic` issue

Comment: no everything is working now. no errors! however i got some utf8 conversion errors

Answer (score 1):

```
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/book_icon.gif, skipping
```

It's rdoc gem problem i'll find this [issue](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/190) on github.
Update rdoc gem and reinstall rails.

```
$ gem install rdoc
$ gem install rails
```

Comment: does it has any effects. my setup is running all well.?

Comment: i think it just closed problem with convert docs from ASCII to UTF

Comment: Also i find this issue with mkmf.rb http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/ruby-gem-install-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby-problem/ and this stack ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731904/rails-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-with-cannot-load-such-file-mkmf in os x for rails we must install Xcode (he included much libs) but in othe linux,bsd based os we must install needed libs manually & so sorry for my rus english :)