# Ruby on Rails Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, terminal, rubygems

I just installed rails on OSX maverick for the first time today and am trying to make a new applications but it was missing gems and some file in the app that tried to make, I ran 
"Bundle install" and this error keeps popping up on terminal.

"An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'` succeeds before bundling."

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: could you add the output of your `ruby --version` command? I guess this highly depends on the version of ruby that is picked up. It might also be helpful to post the contents of your `Gemfile`

Comment: Did you do what it says and try doing a gem install for atomic?

Comment: here is ruby version ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

Comment: The install atomic did not work

Answer (score 0):

JDK8 required for atomic gem. Try to switch to JDK8, or force rvm version:

```
$rvm get head
$rvm --force 2.0.0
$gem update
$gem install atomic
```

This is a similar Q: [Error during rails install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462079/error-during-rails-install)

Comment: actually it did not tried to add controllers and this came up