# bcrypt-ruby gem Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bcrypt-ruby

Good day.
I'm trying to set up project that's beings worked on by other people.
when i run `bundle install` it crashes with an error

```
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/halfros/.bundler/tmp/9279/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/halfros/.bundler/tmp/9279/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'**

```
$ sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
```

Tried ths - no changes.
http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/02/bundle-install-on-linux-giving-error.html

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ruby development library isn't installed.

It also looks like you're using global ruby/gems installation, so your easiest fix is to install the `ruby1.9-dev` package (or something similar), and try again.

Alternatively, you could use rvm and this problem will fix itself:  https://rvm.io/

Comment: @Jesse's link above contains both of these answers.  As does google.

Comment: Didn't find the right answer when I looked for it in google. i use rvm.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a global ruby installation?  What is the output of `which ruby`?  If you were using rvm, the devel includes would be available to the build process.  Read more about compiling native extensions here:  http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/31/dont-be-terrified-of-building-native-extensions