# Installing sqlite3 gem is not working on my Linux Mint x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rhomobile

I've found lots of these questions around, but none of the solutions given work. I also haven't seen x64 mentioned, so maybe that is related.

The issue is this:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

What I've tried so far:

- installing `sqlite3` & `libsqlite3-dev` through apt
- installing `sqlite3` using newest binaries from http://www.sqlite.org/
- specifying sqlite3-dir (`gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/lib`)

I'm a little desperate at this point. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)

This says it can't find the file `mkmf`. This file comes with `-dev` ruby builds. For `ruby1.9.1` like you're error message says you're running, you need to have `ruby1.9.1-dev` installed

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

---

Mint is just a derivative of Ubuntu, so it's worth your while to search for people running Ubuntu having issues like this as well. For example: [`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the sqlite3-ruby gem.

Comment: It's installed for me but I still get an error when running the bundle install. ALWAYS fails on the sqlite3 gem, regardless of whether it's installed with apt-get or aptitude. Never installs correctly.