# Error when installing the CarrierWave gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to install the CarrierWave gem for my Ruby on Rails application. When I go to the command prompt and type `sudo gem install carrierwave` I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing carrierwave:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.13/ext/gem_make.out
```

What on earth does this mean and how do I fix it?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of advice here: [`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

It general, it sounds like you probably need to install some build tools.