# Cannot install ruby serialport through gems

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, serial-port, ruby-1.9

I was trying to install the serialport package to ruby 1.9 on Ubuntu using the following command:

```
gem install serialport
```

And I get the following error:

```
Fetching: serialport-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing serialport:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/serialport-1.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/serialport-1.1.0/ext/native/gem_make.out
```

How do I fix this so that I can install serialport?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ruby dev package to install this properly. Try

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: can also use the following to match your ruby version automatically: sudo apt-get install ruby-dev