# Ember.js Error "`gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling" while building code from source

Tags: ember.js

I came across following issue while building ember from source, how can i fix this.

$ bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

Resolving dependencies...

Using rake (10.1.0)

Installing json (1.8.1)

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /home/suraj/.bundler/tmp/14570/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/suraj/.bundler/tmp/14570/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

seeing this i ran

sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'

which resulted is following error:

Building native extensions.
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in ''

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to install ruby-dev from the debian repositories:

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Kali linux, faced this problem while installing SNORBY after SNORT and Barnyard2,
Following commands resolved the prob:-

**bundle update** and then
**bundle install**