# Trying to install a ruby gem and getting no-where

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, installation

I'm trying to install a gem in debian using

```
gem install typhoeus
```

but I just keep getting this error message.  I've tried a few things but they obviously didn't work.  Could use some ideas, I'm new to both unix and ruby so go easy =)

```
root@asdf:/home/asdf# gem install typhoeus
Fetching: ffi-1.9.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing typhoeus:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -r ./siteconf20140719-30469-1rufzif.rb extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

Here's the gem from github:
https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer here...

[`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Seems you need to install the development package for ruby on your system.  You should be able to do this with either...

```
$ dpkg --install ruby1.9.1-dev.deb
```

...or...

```
$ apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: I ended up installing the development version of ruby (i would have thought every version of ruby was the development version of ruby but guess not).

Comment: On some Linux distro, they separate out -dev versions of software.  For libraries, this means including the headers, so one can link against them.  For Ruby, I guess this means the tools needed to compile native extensions (extensions written in C, rather than Ruby).