# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension message (Linux) installing rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, linux-mint

I'm going through the rails tutorial atm. (I'm a beginner so bear with me.)

As you can see below, when I try and install the rubygems using 'bundle install', I get the error message saying that I need to make sure 'gem install json -v '1.8.1' succeeds before I try again.

But when I try and sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1', I get the

---

.

If I'm asking a stupid question, or if I've left out any necessary info, just let me know. I'm new to this -- CodeAcademy & RailsForZombies are the extent of my knowledge.

```
ben@ben-X551CA ~/first_rails_project/bens_first_app $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.41
Using activesupport 4.0.8
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.8
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.8
Using activemodel 4.0.8
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.8
Using bundler 1.7.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.8
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.0.2
Using jquery-rails 3.0.4
```

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20140908-2757-18q0kfn/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20140908-2757-18q0kfn/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

ben@ben-X551CA ~/first_rails_project/bens_first_app $ gem install json -v '1.8.1'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.
ben@ben-X551CA ~/first_rails_project/bens_first_app $ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

`/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb`

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
ben@ben-X551CA ~/first_rails_project/bens_first_app $

Comment: It's just a error because of the permission to the system, change permission with roor user and try again.

Comment: Your problem is `cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)` and there are dozens of questions about this error on here. You must be using an old tutorial... You should use [RVM](http://rvm.io) instead of your system's built-in Ruby. Abandon this tutorial and find one that uses RVM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So running this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Suppose the `-dev` package was needed?

Comment: +1, it works! Thanks!

Someone please mark this answer.

Comment: If you install GitLab, you can see this error with install rugger bundle. You must install ruby-dev and cmake, without cmake building fails.

Answer (score 1):

If @BenLawton answer doesn't work try this (work for me on Ubuntu 16.04):

`sudo apt-get install ruby-full`

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#apt