# Can't start rails server because "Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, bundler

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 4.0.0

Bundler version 1.7.9
```

When I go to my project folder and run 'rails server' I get the following error:

```
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run 'bundle install' it does something but then give the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run gem install json -v '1.8.1' I get the following error:

```
Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
```

gem install json -v '1.8.1' -V

```
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Installing gem json-1.8.1
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/.gitignore
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/.travis.yml
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/CHANGES
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/COPYING
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/COPYING-json-jruby
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/GPL
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/Gemfile
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/README-json-jruby.markdown
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/README.rdoc
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/Rakefile
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/TODO
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/VERSION
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/data/example.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/data/index.html
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/data/prototype.js
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/diagrams/.keep
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/fbuffer/fbuffer.h
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/depend
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/extconf.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/generator.c
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/generator.h
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/depend
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/extconf.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.c
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.h
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.rl
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/install.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/ByteListTranscoder.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Generator.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorMethods.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorService.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorState.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/OptionsReader.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Parser.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Parser.rl
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/ParserService.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/RuntimeInfo.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/StringDecoder.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/StringEncoder.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Utils.java
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/json-java.gemspec
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/json.gemspec
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/json_pure.gemspec
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/bigdecimal.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/complex.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/core.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/date.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/date_time.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/exception.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/ostruct.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/range.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/rational.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/regexp.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/struct.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/symbol.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/time.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/.keep
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/generic_object.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/generator.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/version.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail1.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail10.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail11.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail12.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail13.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail14.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail18.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail19.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail2.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail20.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail21.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail22.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail23.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail24.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail25.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail27.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail28.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail3.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail4.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail5.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail6.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail7.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail8.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail9.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass1.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass15.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass16.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass17.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass2.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass26.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass3.json
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/setup_variant.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_addition.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_encoding.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_fixtures.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generate.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generic_object.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_string_matching.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_unicode.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tools/fuzz.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tools/server.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_addition.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_encoding.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_fixtures.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generate.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generic_object.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_string_matching.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_unicode.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Can please someone help me with this problem?, thank you!

Comment: You are probably missing some dependency/library, but with the current information that is unclear. Please run `gem install json -v '1.8.1' -V` (notice the extra `-V` flag) in order to get verbose output, so the actual problem is hopefully shown. And update/edit your question to add this new information.

Comment: I updated it like you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113213/246263) you need the ruby development package (ruby-dev).

If you use Debian/Ubuntu you can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

If not, you need corresponding command to install the package for your OS.

Comment: Thank you so much Veger. The solution in the comments 'sudo apt-get install ruby-dev' helped me. After that i did 'bundle install' and the rails server is working!!