# bundle install fails installing ffi (1.9.6)

Tags: rubygems, bundler

ON ubuntu 12.04 Drupalpro Development VM

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20150224-3385-1j3fayi/ffi-1.9.6/gems/ffi-1.9.6 for inspection.
    Results logged to /tmp/bundler20150224-3385-1j3fayi/ffi-1.9.6/gems/ffi-1.9.6/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok After reading this question
[Answer for `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

1. Find out what version of ruby you are using `$ruby -v`
2. Mine was ruby 1.8.7
3. Then install the dev version of this by `$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.8.7-dev`

After installing the dev version the bundler will work