# Unable to Install Shoes :ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shoes

I am beginner in ruby and wanted to install and GUI toolkit. So i surfed web and found shoes was one toolkit so i downloaded the ".install" file it didn't work saying some permission error, then i downloaded the older version which was ".run" format and that too didn't work so i found a gem of shoes when i try to download i get the below in ruby. i downloaded this shoes from git and still facing some error.

```
root@Drona:/home/naren/shoes4# gem install bundler && bundle install
Successfully installed bundler-1.10.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.10.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.10.5...
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using after_do 0.3.1
Using ast 2.0.0
Using parser 2.2.2.6
Using astrolabe 1.3.0
Using benchmark-ips 2.2.0
Using bouncy-castle-java 1.5.0147
Using docile 1.1.5
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

the above is the terminal output.
Ruby version installed is :

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

someone help we out with this installation
and if i have done anything wrong in installation of shoes then let me know

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal directory it seems like you are trying to install shoes4 on ruby 1.9.3. To install shoes4 you need JRuby and a JDK - please follow the instructions [in the readme](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4#installing-shoes-4)

Shoes 3 can't be installed through `gem install` due to the way it was built. For Shoes 3 you need the install script, I recommend the appropriate Shoes 3.2 version [from this page](http://shoesrb.com/downloads/). If this fails with some error please let us know the error so we can help :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the gem program to install shoes.  If on your command line you type gem install shoes you should be fine.

to use it in an app, you would need to create a Gemfile and run Bundle install within your folder

Comment: The normal `shoes` gem is a placeholder gem that doesn't really work. You can use JRuby and do `gem install shoes --pre` to get a working version (that's version 4, shoes 3 does not work as a gem install). The best way to get shoes3 working is the mentioned install/run files.