# Unable to install Rails. Getting Error message.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ubuntu is such a pain sometimes. I am trying to install a specific version of rails (4.2.2) for the Rails tutorial I am doing and my commandline is screaming this code at me in response. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

I first put...

`sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.2`

and then I get this big ugly thing...

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror).

Also, you seem to be using a default system ruby installed via `apt-get`. Consider using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) instead, as it automatically takes care of installing missing dependencies via your package manager.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to update your RubyGems because Rails 4.2 requires the latest version of RubyGems. Run `gem update --system` to get the latest dependencies and then `gem install rails -v 4.2.2` and the error should go away.

Comment: It says that Debian doesn't support that command because it could possibly break my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: What Ruby version you have?

Comment: Another point to mention, use @tompave's answer to get [RVM](http://rvm.io) and install Ruby 2.2.2 or your version of preference.

Comment: Below the vote up/down buttons, there is a check button and click it to award the user for the most helpful answer.