# Error install json 1.8.3 with ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

```
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150731-19716-1hmuzm4.rb extconf.rb
Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150731-19716-1hmuzm4.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/projects/myapp/releases/20150730121841/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/projects/myapp/releases/20150730121841/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Help me fixing this issues. I have tried lot of things, but could not fix it.

Comment: do you have all libraries installed for json

Comment: It looks like you're just out of memory. Can you try doing this again and check to see if you have any free memory? Try to add swap memory.

Comment: I think some libraries could be missing, but I do not know which one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror this is the answer

Comment: @Arun This is production server and it is new one. I don't think its memory issue.

Comment: @ashwinkumar Which server are you using? AWS? Beacuse error message clearly states that "Cannot allocate memory -"

Comment: @RajarshiDas It did not worked. I already installed them.
My server is
Ruby on Rails on 14.04 (Postgres, Nginx, Unicorn) from digitalocean

Comment: @ashwinkumar please check this out!! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/bundler-cannot-allocate-enough-memory-on-ruby-on-rails-application-using-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: @arun I will give a try.

Comment: @Arun It worked. Can you please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ashwinkumar It looks like you're just out of memory. Can you try doing this again and check to see if you have any free memory? Try to add swap memory please check this out!! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/bundler-cannot-allocate-enough-memory-on-ruby-on-rails-application-using-ubuntu-12-10